Python: Plotting a Basemap in the x-y-plane of a 3d plot
I am trying to get the code contained in
https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basemap3d.html
to work. However, I get an error already in the first snippet:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

map = Basemap()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

'''
ax.azim = 270
ax.elev = 90
ax.dist = 5
'''

ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))
ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.35))

plt.show()

The error reads:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../main.py", line 16, in <module>
    ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 2314, in add_collection3d
    collection = super().add_collection(col)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2260, in add_collection
    self._set_artist_props(collection)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1177, in _set_artist_props
    a.axes = self
    ^^^^^^
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 302, in axes
    raise ValueError("Can not reset the axes.  You are probably "
ValueError: Can not reset the axes.  You are probably trying to re-use an artist in more than one Axes which is not supported

Process finished with exit code 1

I cannot find a solution to this yet. My final goal is to achieve something similar to what user guidocioni shows here: https://community.plotly.com/t/adding-a-world-map-to-a-3d-volume-graph-python/33592/2

The copyright on the page you gave is 2014 and on the Github the last commits were 5/10 years ago so maybe try to use Matplotlib version at that time or use another library.

Thanks @rehaqds. I also realized how old the copyright is. Do you have any suggestion of a modern library I can use?

I don't know any, sorry

The basemap library is still maintained.  This basemap tutorial documentation appears to be a separate project from the library.

@RuthC I tried to inform ChatGPT that basemap is still mantained. Now they tell me that basemap is mantained again, but I'm curious if they answer everyone else with the updated info...

drawcoastlines creates a Matplotlib LineCollection and adds that to a 2D axes before returning it.  Modern Matplotlib does not let you add the same artist to two axes.  We can instead create a LineCollection directly from the coastsegs attribute and add that to the 3D axes.  drawcountries is similar, except that it calls a private method to make sure the cntrysegs attribute exists.  So as a workaround I add first add the countries to a 2D plot, which is then discarded.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

map = Basemap()

# Draw and discard a dummy 2D plot so that country data is added as the
# cntrysegs attribute.
dummy_fig, dummy_ax = plt.subplots()
map.drawcountries(ax=dummy_ax)
plt.close(dummy_fig)

# Create the figure and 3D axes we are actually going to use.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Create and add boundary LineCollections.
coastlines = LineCollection(map.coastsegs, linewidth=0.25, color='black')
countries = LineCollection(map.cntrysegs, linewidth=0.35, color='black')
ax.add_collection3d(coastlines)
ax.add_collection3d(countries)

# Set global x and y limits.
ax.set_xlim(-180, 180)
ax.set_ylim(-90, 90)

plt.show()


